# NSCoding in Swift 3 - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppName.User encodeWithCoder:]

Tags: swift, swift3, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I have issues to implement NSCoding. Here is my code for User Class:

```
public class User: NSCoder {
...
```

**NSCoding methods:**

Decoder:

```
required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.deviceToken = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: kUserDeviceTokenKey) as? String
    self.postalCode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:kUserPostalCodeKey) as? String
    self.latitude = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:kUserLatitudeKey) as? Float
    self.views = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey:kUserViewsKey) as? Int
...
```

Encoder:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(deviceToken, forKey: kUserDeviceTokenKey)
    aCoder.encode(postalCode, forKey: kUserPostalCodeKey)
    aCoder.encode(latitude, forKey: kUserLatitudeKey)
    aCoder.encode(views, forKey: kUserViewsKey)
...
```

Save & Load methods:

```
public func save(user : User){
    let encodedUser = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: user)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedUser, forKey: kUserLogedKey)
}

public func getUserLoged()  -> User?{
    if let userData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kUserLogedKey),
        let user = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: userData as! Data) as? User{
        print("DICT USER LOGED: \(user.dictionaryRepresentation())")
        return user
    }else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And i recive following error:

```
-[App.User encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101946e00
2017-03-05 14:22:47.540798 App[2642:750699] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[.User encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101946e00'
```

Comment: Typo: `public class User: NSCoder` vs. `public class User: NSCoding`

Comment: Thanks! and i miss NSObject.
    `public class User: NSObject, NSCoding {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @vadian for solution:

I replaced: `public class User: NSCoder` 
by: `public class User: NSObject, NSCoding`

Comment: Does it mean NSObject now has to be added to every class?